# Custom jQuery "pop up" not displaying in IE8

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, internet-explorer-8

(Site going public very very soon, please help ASAP!)

So I created a pop up (not a true modal but just a hidden div that gets shown with jQuery and hidden again on close). It's displaying correctly in the latest versions of Safari, Firefox and Chrome as well as IE9. But in IE8, it's as if the div isn't even there.

Here's the jQuery:

```
    permalinkBehavior: function(){
$('a[name=permalink]').click(function(event) {
    $('.permalink_overlay').hide();
    $(this).next('.permalink_overlay').show();
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').focus();
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').select();
    return false;
    });
    $(".permalink-cancel").click(function() {
        $(this).parent('.permalink_overlay').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').blur();
        });
    },
```

The class .permalink_overlay is a div with css display:none; (the script takes care of showing and hiding the div when the link is clicked) and relatively positioned to a containing

which is inside  tags. We're using the usual IE hacks, including HTML5Shiv, Selectivizr and conditionals to boot. Also made sure parent element hasLayout and containing elements have position:relative.

Need to resolve this so we can go public. Any advice or known workarounds will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a JS Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net, so it can be debugged.

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? Is IE8 stuck in quirksmode?

Comment: Any errors in the console? I use html5shiv, selectivzr and conditional comments every day and don't get this problem...

Comment: Maxedison: No errors in the console. We're using an emulator (crossbrowsertesting) to test the site, and as far as I can tell it's not set up to be in quirksmode. I'll do the JS Fiddle thing in a few.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a[name=permalink]').click(function(event) {
            $('.permalink_overlay').hide();
            $(this).next('.permalink_overlay').show();
            $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').focus();
            $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').select();
            return false;
        });
        $(".permalink-cancel").click(function() {
            $(this).parent('.permalink_overlay').hide();
            $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').blur();
        });

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .permalink_overlay
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
<div>
    <a href="#" name="permalink">overlay</a>
    <div class="permalink_overlay">
        <input type="text" value="name" /><a href="#" class="permalink-cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have, except that the link itself and the permalink_overlay div is nested inside an <li>. But thanks for the input.

Comment: RESOLVED. Culprit was PIE.htc. Replaced styles with background image and now script works as it should.